# there's no working way to disable the menu Copy / Past / Cut ? it keep showing java

Tags: java, android

i need Help, i'm working on a Simple Text Editor and i want to implement a custom Menu Copy Past Cut .. and more, but to do that i need to Hide the Original Menu, My problem is just in this Step of Hiding the original Menu (Copy.. Past..) it Kepp showing while using the common ways, such as the first bellow Code.

this way not working at all.
and also the way of disabling the long click (if disabling the Long click we can't select the Text) and if text not selected can't use my custom menu.

in some Application such as Code Editor, have this function :

[image: Code Editor]

so, which way i follow to implement this ? can you guide/help me plz ! bcz now all steps is ok for me (when selecting text my menu appear) But also the original Menu (copy past cut) appear and i want to disable it...

the Code Bellow not working and the screen shot show that

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[image: screenshot show that the above code note working]

Comment: Definitely not an answer, but: why would you want to disable it?

Comment: @Michiel to show My own custom Menu on the Top of Editor

Comment: Isn't it because all functions return `false`, indicating the default menu should be shown? Is the callback called?

Comment: @Michiel yes in my device android 10 the bar still show after trying all ways

Comment: So what if you return `true` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution with help of guide in web, and with my own search, no body wanted to share the solution with me.
after i got it, i want to share with you. maybe it helps someone.
the suggestions shared all not working, some will disable selecting texts and others also do this + not working on all api..

[image]

in my case the editText id is edittext1.

in your activity past the bellow code :

```
private class MyActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        private Menu mMenu;
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            //After the menu is created, the object is obtained for subsequent operations
            this.mMenu=menu;
            mMenu.clear();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    }
```

and how to use it :

```
edittext1.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new MyActionModeCallback());
```

Comment: I find this answer insulting. You claim that nobody wanted to help you. Perhaps nobody had the information you needed. Perhaps they couldn't see what you needed from your question.

Comment: First, you are only supposed to ask a single question. Second, you are claiming malice where there is none. You are insulting the volunteers here who may not have ever tried to override this sort of system menu.